# Dokku cannot see log, "Application's container not found"

Tags: ruby, logging, dokku

I am deploying my app on dokku. I have not yet deploy successfully because error in deployment step. I want to see log but Dokku said that "Application's container not found"

```
root@dokku-s-1vcpu-3gb-sgp1-01:~# dokku apps:list
=====> My Apps
world_cup_json
root@dokku-s-1vcpu-3gb-sgp1-01:~# dokku logs world_cup_json
Application's container not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved** 
We can see logs once the apps is deployed (deployed successfully). My apps is not deploy yet so I cannot see log.